# Maximize $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n m_i$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Someone visits a market where one hundred different types of
fruit are sold. All types cost $1$ euro per pound. The utility the buyer receives
from buying $m_1$ pounds of the first type of fruit he buys, $m_2$ pounds of the
second type, etc. (all integer numbers) is $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n m_i$. Here $n$ is the number of different types of fruit he buys. The buyer has $100$ euros.
Which fruits shouldhe buy with which quantities to maximise his utility?

---

I thought about maximizing $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ln m_i$ instead but I don't really know how to include the ordering of the utilities that the $m_i$'s result in. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Buying the maximum amount of the $m_i$ that is the greatest would maximize the utility, correct?  Is there some restriction that makes this question more interesting?

Comment: Hint: Think in terms of Arithmetic Mean Geometric Mean Inequality. Note that the title and the text are currently incompatible.

Comment: @AndréNicolas My bad, I fixed the title. I am not really familiar with the inequality that you mentioned. I think there should be a way to solve this by using Larange multipliers (as most problems in this course use this technique).

Comment: @SteveKass What Andre Nicolas probably meant is that the text mentions a maximization, and I by accident typed 'minimize' instead. To be clear: I meant 'maximize' (I edited it already).

Comment: Ha. I totally missed that! I'll delete my comment if I can so as not to confuse.

Comment: The AM/GM says that for non-negative $x_i$ we have $\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\ge \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}$, with equality (and therefore maximizing the right-hand side) when all the $x_i$ are equal. Sure, you can do it with Lagrange multipliers.  For general numbers it does not quite solve your problem, because of the integrality constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be right on track (except for a typo: $\sum \ln$ instead of $\ln \sum$) if we were looking for solutions in real numbers.
By the integer constraint, an elementary approach seems fuitful (pun not intended).

First of all, if $n>100$ at least one $m_i$ is zero, hence the utility is zero, no matter what the buyer does. So we shall assume henceforth that $n\le 100$ and consider only solutions with $m_i\ge 1$ for all $i$.
Since there are only finitely many possible buying strategies, the existence of a maximum is clear and we may simply look for a solution for which we cannot find an improvement.

Assume we have a solution where $\sum m_i<100$ (i.e. we do not spend all the money - in theory someting like this might indeed be optimal). Then picking any $i$ and replacing $m_i$ with $m_i+1$ still obeys the sum constraint, but increases the (positive!) utility by a factor of $\frac{m_i+1}{m_i}>1$. Hence - as one might have guessed - all optimal solutions spend all the oney, $\sum m_i=100$.

Assume we have solution where $m_i>m_j+1$ for some $i,j$. Then by replacing $m_i$ with $m_i-1$ and $m_j$ with $m_j+1$ we obtain another valid solution (the total fruit count does not change) and the (positive!) utility gets multiplied with
$$\frac{m_i-1}{m_i}\cdot \frac{m_j+1}{m_j}=\frac{1-\frac1{m_i}}{1-\frac1{m_j+1}}>\frac{1-\frac1{m_i}}{1-\frac1{m_i}}=1.$$
Hence this situation does not occur for the optimal solution(s). We conclude that ther is an $m$ such that $m_i\in\{m,m+1\}$ for all $i$. More precisely, if there are exactly $k$ indices $i$ where $m_i=m+1$ then the utility is
$$ (m+1)^km^{n-k}=m^n\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^k$$
which is (for fixed $m$) strictly increasing with $k$, i.e. we want to maximize $k$. Then again, we have the constraint that 
$$100=(n-k)m+k(m+1) = nm+k  $$
and of course $0\le k\le n$. A solution with $k=n$ is equivalent to the solution with $k=0$ and $m$ replaced with  $m+1$, hence we may assume $0\le k<n$. Bu tthat brings us to division with remainder, which is unique: We *must* set $m=\lfloor \frac {100}n\rfloor$ and $k=100\mod n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the elaborate explanation! This helps a lot! I highly appreciate your help!

Comment: In case it isn't clear, Hagen has shown you how to find the maximum utility for a given $n$, so it still remains for you to calculate the utility for each of the 100 possible values of $n$ and choose the largest.

Comment: @SteveKass Yes, that is what I was just thinking about actually. But it doesn't really seem efficient to enumerate all the possibilities. Any ideas?

Comment: @HagenVonEitzen Could you please tell me what I could try so as to maximize this over all values of n?

Comment: It's not hard using something like Mathematica. I think this is the correct function: http://i.imgur.com/Mdsjmol.png

Comment: @SteveKass The solutions tell me that the answer should be 34, so this could be correct. Thank you.

Comment: It turns out the utility for $n=33$ and 34 are the same, by the way! For $n=33$, you buy 3 pounds each of 32 kinds and 4 pounds of one. For $n=34$, you buy 2 pounds of two kinds, then 3 pounds of 32 kinds.

Answer (score 2):

**Note: This answer forgot to take into account that the $m_i$ all have to be integers, so it's not correct...**

The fruits all have the same utility, so there's no need to consider the order in which they're purchased.

It's an easy exercise to show that the maximum product of $n$ positive numbers with a given sum is obtained when the numbers are all equal.  Using that, the buyer can obtain utility 100 if he or she purchases only 1 kind of fruit, $50\cdot50$ if he or she purchases 2 kinds, and so on. There are only 100 possibilities, and you could find the largest by computing them all. Or you could maximize the product $\left(\frac{100}{k}\right)^k$ using calculus and compare the result of using integer values of $k$ nearest the maximum.